# Match second instance

Tags: c#, regex, match

I have a string like this, and I only want to find if it contains 'N2' in it, but not 'EN2', so that should be disregarded:

```
EN2T65G872N2ULKJJDLO05
```

It always would start with EN2 at the beginning, if that helps, but the N number could be different like N3 for instance. I just don't want it to incorrectly identify a unit as N2 unless it actually contains that

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: `(?<!E)N2` if i understand what you are asking... Zero-width negative lookbehind assertion. Continues matching only if subpattern does not match on the left

Comment: The question can use some more examples (matching and non-matching). The tag wiki for regex has more advice that can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var rx = new Regex("(?:^EN[0-9].*?)(N[0-9])");

var match = rx.Match(str);

if (match.Success)
{
    var nx = match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

The `^` means beginning-of-the-string, `(?:  )` is non-capturing group, because we aren't interested in it, `.*?` is any character any number of times but non-greedy.

Comment: The OP isnt after the E at the stat of the string which is what youre regex is providing.

Comment: @SimonPrice Note the use of the non-capturing group, and the fact that for extracting the value of the second `Nx` I'm using `Groups[1].Value`.

Comment: I think this is possibly down to how the question is worded, I took it as wants N2, so EN2 does contain N2 so yes there are two matches I would have dropped the E and taken the N2 at index 0.  But I guess its down to what the OP means and how they view the data

Comment: This works great, but how could I amend this to work if the front few letters change, for instance EI4 instead of EN2?

Comment: @J.James Unclear what you are asking. `N2` can't be the *second* instance if the first instance is `EI4`

Comment: Essentially, if the string starts with EN2 yet contains N5 in it for instance, it would match this as N2 because it recognises the N2 first. Your solution works fine if the string always starts with ENX for instance, but would not work if the string started with a different prefix.

Comment: @J.James You asked the **second instance**. Give examples of other strings.

Answer (score 0):

Use grouping to match second case: `N2.*?(N2)`

https://regex101.com/r/005u2q/1

For *N number could be different* use: `N\d.*?(N\d)`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this and let me know if this is the regex that you would want to use to get the values.  You will see in the example that this will get an N2 and an N3 value in the string so you will need to get the matched values into a list or an array and then pick out the first N2, N3 Nx that youre looking for.

https://regexr.com/3pso3

This unlike other answers here will only get the N and the next numeric digit

Answer (score -1):

You could use [negative lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in your regex:

```
(?<!E)N[0-9]
```

This regex will match any sequence containing the "N" character: not preceded by the "E" character; followed by any digit.
Here is an example: [RegExr](https://regexr.com/3pslu).

Comment: Your example is getting the second N2, but missing the first

Comment: I believe the question explicitly says it should not match "N2" if there is a "E" right before, is not that the case?

Comment: quoting the question: "I only want to find if it contains 'N2' in it, but not 'EN2', so that should be disregarded"